# Scrapy - Pass scraped URLs through a Spider

Tags: python, subdomain, scrapy, conditional-statements, web-crawler

I am new to Scrapy and Python, and with all of the documentation I am getting a little confused and overloaded with new info!

My project is to firstly locate and scrape the URLs of blogs of a certain category.  This process i'm quite comfortable with.  However, to achieve my end result, i'd like to pass these urls through a stats website - say, hypestat.com.  As you can see with this query (http://pinterest.com.hypestat.com/), to gain the stats info, the website you query appears in the base url as a subdomain.

Is there a way to craft a spider to loop through a whole array of these urls and prepend them to hypestat.com?

If anybody could point me in the right direction, that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can issue Request to appended Hypestat URL in blog parsing function and pass a callback function to process result from hypestat

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    subjects = hxs.select("//div[@class='BlogList']")
    for subject in subjects:
        item = BlogItem()
        url =  "http://"+subject.select('a/@href').extract()+".hypestat.com"
        request =  Request(url,  callback = self.parse_statdetail)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

def parse_statdetail(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item ["origin"] = response.url
    item ["stat"] = hxs.select("//div[@class='website_report_text']/b/text()").extract()[2])
    yield item
```

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#basespider-example

Comment: Thank you so much, this is fantastic! Helped me get my head around it a bit more :)